# Cannot load OpenIE model when using the open source version of CoreNLP

Tags: java, serialization, nlp, stanford-nlp

I downloaded the source code of coreNLP from [this page](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) and the model recommended in the README file. I create a new project in eclipse and tried to run openie by it return the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Could not load clause splitter model at edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.<init>(OpenIE.java:201)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.openie(AnnotatorImplementations.java:272)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$20.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:654)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:89)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:403)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:142)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:138)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.demo.Demo.main(Demo.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.ClauseSplitterSearchProblem$8; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4145523451314579506, local class serialVersionUID = -7360029270983346606
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:325)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.ClauseSplitter.load(ClauseSplitter.java:283)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.<init>(OpenIE.java:196)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Is this with the most recent models jar? This can be downloaded from [this link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar) (warning: large few hundred MB download).

Comment: Yes i used the jar that you mentioned

Comment: Do you get the error if you run from the command line?

Comment: The bug disapear if a use the pre-compiled jar, but I must change some parts in the code before running it

Comment: I suppose that it should run without any bug using the source code version of CoreNLP

Comment: Are you changing the source code? There are changes to the source code that could potentially break serialization; but, by default, the GitHub version of the code should load properly with the most recent models jar... Can you post the sequence of commands you ran to replicate this bug?

Comment: I loaded the source code ([CoreNLP-master](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP)) into a new project in eclipse, than i ran (before changing the code) the demo method described in [this page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml#History). While using the `stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar` model.

Comment: Can you try running it from the command line? Something like: `ant && java -mx4g -cp classes/:stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE`

Comment: I ran the OpenIE class main method in eclipse (same thing as running it from command line) and its return the same error.

Comment: I'm trying to debug whether this is a classpath bug in the Eclipse configuration, or a bug in the code. If it works from the command line, it is a bug in your Eclipse configuration; otherwise it is a bug in the code.

Comment: I try before to run the  stanford-openie.jar from command line and its work perfectly

Comment: I tried to run the source code from command line as you told me and it return the same error

Comment: However the same problem occur when i use the OpenIE source code and its specific model in [this page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml#History). So I think that there is a bug in that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the following steps:

1. clone the repo from GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP.git
2. download the latest model jar at: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar
3. cd CoreNLP ; ant
4. at this point you should have built the latest version of the code on GitHub
5. set CLASSPATH to include CoreNLP/classes, CoreNLP/lib and the latest models jar
6. run this command: java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.naturalli.OpenIE

It works fine, so I don't think there are any problems with what we are currently distributing.